# Memory Management: Releasing Custom Objects in constructor - Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, nsobject

I have an `init` method that takes values from a `NSDictionary`. This is within my `Friend` object.

My question is when do I release this particular instantiation of `Friend`?

```
- (id)initWithValue:(NSString *)value {
    Friend *friend = [[Friend alloc] init];
    friend.friendId = [value valueForKeyPath:@"id"];
    friend.friendName = [value valueForKeyPath:@"name"];

    return friend;
}
```

I call the `init` method below to add the `Friend` objects to a `friends` array

```
for (id value in dataDict) {
    Friend *friend = [[Friend alloc] initWithValue:value];
    [friends addObject:friend];
    [friend release];
}
```

I then do the following in code:

```
Friend *friend = (Friend *)[friends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

If I `autorelease` the `Friend` object in the `init` method then I get a message was sent to deallocated instance when I use the above code to get the particular objects value based on the `indexPath.row`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly answering your question, but these lines of code are definitely dangerous:

```
- (id)initWithValue:(NSString *)value {
    Friend *friend = [[Friend alloc] init];
```

Instead, you should write like this:

```
- (id)initWithValue:(NSString *)value {
    [super init];
    self.friendId = ...;
    self.friendName = ...;

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Later on down the track I actually went with the initWithValue way of doing things. It just makes more sense and it doesn't mean I have to initialise the object in the actual method. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things:

- an `init` method should not be calling `alloc` (see diwup's example for the right way to do an `init`)
- it looks like what you're trying to do is make a convenience method that creates, initializes, and returns an (autoreleased) object (similar to `+NSString stringWithFormat:` etc.). You've almost got it, but you need to (a) not name it "init*", and (b) make it a class method, not an instance method.

Something like:

```
+ (Friend)friendWithValue:(NSString *)value {
    Friend *friend = [[[Friend alloc] init] autorelease];
    friend.friendId = [value valueForKeyPath:@"id"];
    friend.friendName = [value valueForKeyPath:@"name"];

    return friend;
}
```

You would use that like:

```
[friends addObject:[Friend friendWithValue:value]];
```

Comment: Thank you for providing such an informative answer. Everything now makes sense, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

And directly answering it: Release your allocated objects ONLY when you are done with them. Create a method and call [object release]; for all your allocated objects. Doing so, you avoid having memory allocation inconsistencies, and this approach is better then calling autorelease.